# Getting NullPointerException while connecting with ignite server node

Tags: java, weblogic, ignite, distributed-system

I have multiple Clients which are getting started as a embedded mode on a weblogic server and standalone server node is exists inside a docker container. Both the server and client nodes are on the same machine.

below are the exceptions are printed on clients end.

```
Mar 30, 2021 11:53:25 AM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger error
SEVERE: Exception in discovery notyfier worker thread.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.addClientNode(GridDiscoveryManager.java:445)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.ClusterCachesInfo.processCacheChangeRequests(ClusterCachesInfo.java:596)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.ClusterCachesInfo.onCacheChangeRequested(ClusterCachesInfo.java:430)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.onCustomEvent(GridCacheProcessor.java:3827)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager$4.onDiscovery0(GridDiscoveryManager.java:697)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager$4.lambda$onDiscovery$0(GridDiscoveryManager.java:604)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager$DiscoveryMessageNotifierWorker.body0(GridDiscoveryManager.java:2667)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager$DiscoveryMessageNotifierWorker.body(GridDiscoveryManager.java:2705)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


and below are the exceptions printed on ignite server node

[11:52:26,066][INFO][grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-1-#25][TcpCommunicationSpi] Accepted incoming communication connection [locAddr=/127.0.0.1:47100, rmtAddr=/127.0.0.1:42966]
[11:53:14,633][INFO][grid-timeout-worker-#23][IgniteKernal] 
Metrics for local node (to disable set 'metricsLogFrequency' to 0)
    ^-- Node [id=b180492a, uptime=3 days, 19:10:25.322]
    ^-- H/N/C [hosts=1, nodes=7, CPUs=8]
    ^-- CPU [cur=0.13%, avg=0.1%, GC=0%]
    ^-- PageMemory [pages=98848]
    ^-- Heap [used=776MB, free=89.33%, comm=4576MB]
    ^-- Off-heap [used=388MB, free=96.82%, comm=1120MB]
    ^--   sysMemPlc region [used=0MB, free=99.21%, comm=40MB]
    ^--   default region [used=387MB, free=96.78%, comm=1040MB]
    ^--   TxLog region [used=0MB, free=100%, comm=40MB]
    ^-- Outbound messages queue [size=0]
    ^-- Public thread pool [active=0, idle=0, qSize=0]
    ^-- System thread pool [active=0, idle=7, qSize=0]
[11:53:14,633][INFO][grid-timeout-worker-#23][IgniteKernal] FreeList [name=null, buckets=256, dataPages=1, reusePages=3]
[11:53:25,830][SEVERE][disco-notifier-worker-#41][GridDiscoveryManager] Exception in discovery notyfier worker thread.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.addClientNode(GridDiscoveryManager.java:445)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.ClusterCachesInfo.processCacheChangeRequests(ClusterCachesInfo.java:596)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.ClusterCachesInfo.onCacheChangeRequested(ClusterCachesInfo.java:430)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.onCustomEvent(GridCacheProcessor.java:3827)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager$4.onDiscovery0(GridDiscoveryManager.java:697)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager$4.lambda$onDiscovery$0(GridDiscoveryManager.java:604)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager$DiscoveryMessageNotifierWorker.body0(GridDiscoveryManager.java:2667)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager$DiscoveryMessageNotifierWorker.body(GridDiscoveryManager.java:2705)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[11:53:25,831][SEVERE][disco-notifier-worker-#41][] Critical system error detected. Will be handled accordingly to configured handler [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0, super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=[SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]], failureCtx=FailureContext [type=SYSTEM_WORKER_TERMINATION, err=java.lang.NullPointerException]]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.addClientNode(GridDiscoveryManager.java:445)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.ClusterCachesInfo.processCacheChangeRequests(ClusterCachesInfo.java:596)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.ClusterCachesInfo.onCacheChangeRequested(ClusterCachesInfo.java:430)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.onCustomEvent(GridCacheProcessor.java:3827)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager$4.onDiscovery0(GridDiscoveryManager.java:697)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager$4.lambda$onDiscovery$0(GridDiscoveryManager.java:604)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager$DiscoveryMessageNotifierWorker.body0(GridDiscoveryManager.java:2667)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager$DiscoveryMessageNotifierWorker.body(GridDiscoveryManager.java:2705)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[11:53:25,833][WARNING][disco-notifier-worker-#41][FailureProcessor] No deadlocked threads detected.
[11:53:26,086][WARNING][disco-notifier-worker-#41][FailureProcessor] Thread dump at 2021/03/30 11:53:26 GMT
Thread [name="sys-#34166", id=34294, state=TIMED_WAITING, blockCnt=0, waitCnt=1]
    Lock [object=java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@3e4db039, ownerName=null, ownerId=-1]
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Thread [name="sys-#34165", id=34293, state=TIMED_WAITING, blockCnt=0, waitCnt=1]
    Lock [object=java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@3e4db039, ownerName=null, ownerId=-1]
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Thread [name="tcp-disco-client-message-worker-#107", id=34285, state=TIMED_WAITING, blockCnt=0, waitCnt=96]
    Lock [object=java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@3f4c221b, ownerName=null, ownerId=-1]
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.pollFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:522)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.poll(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:684)
        at o.a.i.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$MessageWorker.body(ServerImpl.java:7183)
        at o.a.i.i.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
        at o.a.i.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$MessageWorkerThread.body(ServerImpl.java:7119)
        at o.a.i.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:62)

Thread [name="tcp-disco-sock-reader-#106", id=34284, state=RUNNABLE, blockCnt=0, waitCnt=0]
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
        - locked java.io.BufferedInputStream@6cd381b3
        at o.a.i.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshallerInputStreamWrapper.read(JdkMarshallerInputStreamWrapper.java:53)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:2663)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2679)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:3156)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:862)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:358)
        at o.a.i.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshallerObjectInputStream.<init>(JdkMarshallerObjectInputStream.java:43)
        at o.a.i.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.unmarshal0(JdkMarshaller.java:137)
        at o.a.i.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:94)
        at o.a.i.i.util.IgniteUtils.unmarshal(IgniteUtils.java:10086)
        at o.a.i.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$SocketReader.body(ServerImpl.java:6246)
        at o.a.i.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:62)

Thread [name="tcp-disco-sock-reader-#103", id=34263, state=RUNNABLE, blockCnt=2, waitCnt=2]
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
        - locked java.io.BufferedInputStream@215dbeb0
        at o.a.i.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshallerInputStreamWrapper.read(JdkMarshallerInputStreamWrapper.java:53)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:2663)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2679)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:3156)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:862)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:358)
        at o.a.i.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshallerObjectInputStream.<init>(JdkMarshallerObjectInputStream.java:43)
        at o.a.i.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.unmarshal0(JdkMarshaller.java:137)
        at o.a.i.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:94)
        at o.a.i.i.util.IgniteUtils.unmarshal(IgniteUtils.java:10086)
        at o.a.i.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$SocketReader.body(ServerImpl.java:6246)
        at o.a.i.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:62)

Thread [name="tcp-disco-sock-reader-#102", id=34262, state=RUNNABLE, blockCnt=0, waitCnt=0]
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
        - locked java.io.BufferedInputStream@51f37d31
        at o.a.i.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshallerInputStreamWrapper.read(JdkMarshallerInputStreamWrapper.java:53)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:2663)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2679)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:3156)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:862)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:358)
        at o.a.i.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshallerObjectInputStream.<init>(JdkMarshallerObjectInputStream.java:43)
        at o.a.i.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.unmarshal0(JdkMarshaller.java:137)
        at o.a.i.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:94)
        at o.a.i.i.util.IgniteUtils.unmarshal(IgniteUtils.java:10086)
        at o.a.i.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$SocketReader.body(ServerImpl.java:6246)
        at o.a.i.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:62)

Thread [name="tcp-disco-client-message-worker-#101", id=34249, state=TIMED_WAITING, blockCnt=0, waitCnt=384]
    Lock [object=java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@76db00a4, ownerName=null, ownerId=-1]
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.pollFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:522)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.poll(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:684)
        at o.a.i.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$MessageWorker.body(ServerImpl.java:7183)
        at o.a.i.i.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
        at o.a.i.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$MessageWorkerThread.body(ServerImpl.java:7119)
        at o.a.i.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:62)

Thread [name="tcp-disco-client-message-worker-#100", id=34248, state=TIMED_WAITING, blockCnt=0, waitCnt=386]
    Lock [object=java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@713eab82, ownerName=null, ownerId=-1]
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.pollFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:522)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.poll(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:684)
        at o.a.i.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$MessageWorker.body(ServerImpl.java:7183)
        at o.a.i.i.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
        at o.a.i.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$MessageWorkerThread.body(ServerImpl.java:7119)
        at o.a.i.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:62)

Thread [name="tcp-disco-sock-reader-#98", id=34246, state=RUNNABLE, blockCnt=0, waitCnt=0]
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
        - locked java.io.BufferedInputStream@778acb44
        at o.a.i.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshallerInputStreamWrapper.read(JdkMarshallerInputStreamWrapper.java:53)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:2663)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2679)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:3156)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:862)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:358)
        at o.a.i.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshallerObjectInputStream.<init>(JdkMarshallerObjectInputStream.java:43)
        at o.a.i.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.unmarshal0(JdkMarshaller.java:137)
        at o.a.i.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:94)
        at o.a.i.i.util.IgniteUtils.unmarshal(IgniteUtils.java:10086)
        at o.a.i.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$SocketReader.body(ServerImpl.java:6246)
        at o.a.i.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:62)

Thread [name="tcp-disco-client-message-worker-#97", id=34236, state=TIMED_WAITING, blockCnt=0, waitCnt=446]
    Lock [object=java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@597a2b31, ownerName=null, ownerId=-1]
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.pollFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:522)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.poll(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:684)
        at o.a.i.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$MessageWorker.body(ServerImpl.java:7183)
        at o.a.i.i.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
        at o.a.i.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$MessageWorkerThread.body(ServerImpl.java:7119)
        at o.a.i.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:62)

Thread [name="srvc-deploy-#45", id=68, state=WAITING, blockCnt=1, waitCnt=162]
    Lock [object=java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@31b3cad4, ownerName=null, ownerId=-1]
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Thread [name="exchange-worker-#43", id=66, state=TIMED_WAITING, blockCnt=2, waitCnt=65757]
    Lock [object=java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@10c2f74d, ownerName=null, ownerId=-1]
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.pollFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:522)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.poll(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:684)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body0(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:2613)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:2540)
        at o.a.i.i.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Thread [name="ignite-update-notifier-timer", id=65, state=TIMED_WAITING, blockCnt=2, waitCnt=5705]
    Lock [object=java.util.TaskQueue@18e965c7, ownerName=null, ownerId=-1]
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

Thread [name="upd-ver-checker", id=64, state=TIMED_WAITING, blockCnt=0, waitCnt=65592]
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.cluster.GridUpdateNotifier$1.run(GridUpdateNotifier.java:115)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Thread [name="disco-event-worker-#42", id=63, state=WAITING, blockCnt=1, waitCnt=203191]
    Lock [object=java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@2286f22c, ownerName=null, ownerId=-1]
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
        at o.a.i.i.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager$DiscoveryWorker.body0(GridDiscoveryManager.java:2856)
        at o.a.i.i.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager$DiscoveryWorker.body(GridDiscoveryManager.java:2825)
        at o.a.i.i.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)

Thread [name="tcp-disco-msg-worker-#2", id=61, state=RUNNABLE, blockCnt=3, waitCnt=32527715]
        at java.lang.String.intern(Native Method)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamField.<init>(ObjectStreamField.java:107)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.readNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:805)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDescriptor(ObjectInputStream.java:891)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1857)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1751)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2042)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
        at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:797)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2178)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
        at o.a.i.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.unmarshal0(JdkMarshaller.java:139)
        at o.a.i.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:94)
        at o.a.i.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.unmarshal0(JdkMarshaller.java:161)
        at o.a.i.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:82)
        at o.a.i.i.util.IgniteUtils.unmarshal(IgniteUtils.java:10141)
        at o.a.i.spi.discovery.tcp.messages.TcpDiscoveryCustomEventMessage.message(TcpDiscoveryCustomEventMessage.java:81)
        at o.a.i.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.processCustomMessage(ServerImpl.java:5478)
        at o.a.i.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.processMessage(ServerImpl.java:2837)
        at o.a.i.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.processMessage(ServerImpl.java:2611)
        at o.a.i.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$MessageWorker.body(ServerImpl.java:7188)
        at o.a.i.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.body(ServerImpl.java:2700)
        at o.a.i.i.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
        at o.a.i.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$MessageWorkerThread.body(ServerImpl.java:7119)
        at o.a.i.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:62)

Thread [name="main", id=1, state=WAITING, blockCnt=1, waitCnt=6]
    Lock [object=java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch$Sync@20e2f504, ownerName=null, ownerId=-1]
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:997)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
        at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:231)
        at o.a.i.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:334)
[11:53:26,086][SEVERE][disco-notifier-worker-#41][] JVM will be halted immediately due to the failure: [failureCtx=FailureContext [type=SYSTEM_WORKER_TERMINATION, err=java.lang.NullPointerException]]
```

Comment: I have found a similar stack trace. Do you happen to use Ignite services? Does this happen every time?

Comment: No, im not using ignite services. Using it only for caching some data as a plain client-server terminology. Started client as embedded mode on weblogic server as a thick client. And it is happening randomly.

Comment: Please upload and share complete logs from client and server.

Comment: Have you tried the latest Ignite version, 2.10.0?

Comment: @alamar Related logs are attached already in this post from client end. Other then this on the client side, connection exception logs got printed that because of  server went down after NullPointer exception. and on the ignite server end posted exception stack was in the logs other then dis only thread dump was there. Which i could not paste it because of limited character length.

Comment: @alamar currently I m using ignite 2.7.5. 2.10.0 can not use right now because of some company policy and there is no concrete evidence that this is fixed in latest version.

Comment: Please find a way to share complete log files

Comment: @alamar please find the logs with this link : [ignite logs](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pawan-jangid/failure-logs/main/ignite-b180492a.0.log)

Answer (score 0):

I think this may happen if you do some code like this:

```
inputCache = ignite.cache(inputCacheName);
CacheConfiguration configuration = inputCache.getConfiguration(CacheConfiguration.class);
outputCache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(configuration.setName("cache_" + ctx.name()));
```

e.g. you get a cache from running Ignite instance, change its name, and then a new client node comes. Please check that you never do that, instead always create, or at least clone, a new `CacheConfiguration`.

Unfortunately, cache configurations are mutable and we do not check that they are not altered.

Comment: If this is a case as you suggested then it should happen very frequently because there are some places where im using same name to create cache node. And i observed that mostly it happens when we take deployment on our weblogic managed server and restart it. please take a look my client code which deployed on weblogic [Ignite client code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pawan-jangid/failure-logs/main/ApacheIgniteCacheClient.java)

Comment: I think this is the problem. What you should be doing instead is `new CacheConfiguration newCacheCfg = CacheConfiguration(cacheConfig).setName(...);` when getting a cache.

Comment: I have filed a ticket about this issue: [IGNITE-14466](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-14466)

Comment: please let me know i you have any update on this. I checked the ticket "IGNITE-14466" but there is no comments on this.